# Download a file from a remote machine while SSH'd into it?

Tags: ssh

It often happens that I'm SSH'd into another machine and I'd like to download a file onto my local machine without having to open a new terminal and scp. For example, something like this:

```
local $ ssh remote
remote $ ls
remote_file
remote $ download remote_file
…
remote $ ^D
local $ ls
remote_file
```

Is there any way — even a terrible hack — to let me download a file while I'm SSH'd into the remote host, without using SCP?

I'd considered playing some tricks with, ex, `$SSH_CLIENT`, but that won't work when my local machine is behind a NAT (which is basically all the time).

Answer (score 2):

Instead of connecting to the remote machine using ssh use sftp. You will have a ftp client connect to the remote machine using the ssh protocol. When you'll be connect you'll be able to browse the remote machine using `cd` and `ls`. To copy the file in your local machine you'll use the `get remote.file` and the file will be copy to your local machine.

[SFTP informations](https://kb.wisc.edu/cae/page.php?id=32991)